# R BayesFactor Package: Output BF value

Tags: r

I'm working with the BayesFactor Package in R but I can't output the Bayes Factor statistic as a variable to save.

For example, using a t-test paired-sample data design:

```
a = c(94,95,98,99,98,99,96,97,97,100,66,100,99,97,100,99,100,97,99)
b = c(97,100,99,100,100,98,98,97,97,100,67,100,100,98,99,99,100,98,100)
out = ttestBF(a,y = b,paired = T)
```

returns:

```
Bayes factor analysis

[1] Alt., r=0.707 : 4.258084 ±0.03%

Against denominator:

  Null, mu = 0

Bayes factor type: BFoneSample, JZS
```

---

I'd like to be able to save `4.258084` to a variable.

Typically in other R functions I'd access it as:
out$variable_name

But the available options for this output are:

```
(1) out$Alt., r=0.707
(2) out$Null, mu=0
```

And these return errors when called:

```
(1) Error: unexpected ',' in "out$Alt.,"
(2) Error: unexpected ',' in "out$Null,"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I am the author of the BayesFactor package). The easiest way to get the Bayes factor by itself is to simply use

```
as.vector(out)
```

and that will give you the desired number(s). There's no need to go deep in the object structure.

Comment: Thanks Richard. This returned a 'Named num' variable for me:
Alt., r=0.707 
     4.258084
which could then be converted to a numeric variable using as.numeric. So the code that did the trick was:
as.numeric(as.vector(out))

Comment: Yes, since BayesFactor objects can contain more than one Bayes factor, it will try to be helpful and name them so you know which is which. But if you don't need/want them, you can indeed strip them.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to ask the right person and the answer is deeper into the output structure:

The Bayes Factor that you get from "out@bayesFactor$bf" is the LOG of the BayesFactor you want.

So to get the actual BF value:

BF = exp(1)^out@bayesFactor$bf

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, using the `@bayesfator` slot within the returned object gives unexpected results. Here as.vector and as.dataframe (which are correct) don't match the internal slot value:

```
bf10 <- proportionBF(70, 100, .5)

# this is different
bf10@bayesFactor$bf

# to these
bf10 %>% as.vector
bf10 %>% as.data.frame()
```